# Is the highlight not pronounced enough?

Tags: discussion, support, design

Does anyone else feel the highlight:

- on the front page for questions in tags you are following
- for block quotes

is not pronounced enough in the new design?

I can hardly see it.

Votes on the question mean agreement or disagreement that it's too subtle.

Answers:   How do we change it?

Comment: Seems pretty pronounced to me.  It's the same beige as the popular meta posts box over to the right on this page.  What OS and browser are you using?  I'm on Mac OS X using Firefox.

Comment: @Keen:   PC/Chrome  -- I don't think it's the same color.  One is slightly pink and the other is slightly tan/orange?

Comment: this seems like it should have been an answer [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7581/5184)

Comment: @phantom42:   It's exactly [this issue](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7586/3823) -- but how does that answer it?

Comment: it's exactly the sort of feedback they were asking for there.

Answer (score 3):

It looks fine to me; it looks pretty much like Stack Overflow and other sites. Are you not seeing this:

[image]

Don't get me wrong, I much preferred the old color scheme (I'm partial to blues and especially cyan) but even if I don't like the colors they look easy enough to tell apart to me.

Comment: That is what I'm seeing, but it's hard to distinguish.

Comment: I've just realized it's partly an effect on my privacy filter.   If I make sure the screen it perfectly perpendicular to my line of sight it's not as bad.   Still  not good though.

Comment: I'm working on user style sheet (e.g. for Stylish) to switch back to the old colors, I'll let you know when it's done :)